# jQuery AJAX blank page issue with IE9

Tags: jquery

This works in Firefox and Chrome, but fails in IE. It does show results in the alert, but the page is just blank in IE. I don't get any kind of Firebug errors, so I can't pinpoint the issue. Can anyone spot any blatant errors on my end...or know of a workaround?

Thanks.

```
$("#compareit").submit(function(e){
    $("#topsection").hide();
    $("#tabs").hide();
    $("#bottomWrap").hide(); 
    $("#error").html('');
    $("#leftcolumn").hide();
    $("#rightcolumn").hide();
    e.preventDefault();
    var queryString = $('#compareit').serialize();
    var dataString = queryString + "&count=" + totalselected;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'newmlbcompare2.php', 
        cache: false,
        data: dataString,
        success:function(result){
            $('#ajaxDiv').html(result);
            // This alerts the HTML block that is being returned (in all browsers)
            //alert(result);
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Added HTML on request. I've truncated some to save space:

```
<div id="maincontainer">

<div id="topsection"><div id="topImage"></div></div>

<div id="contentwrapper">
<div id="contentcolumn">
<div class="innertube">
<div id="compareWrapper">

<form name="compareit" id="compareit" action="">
<input type="hidden" value="2011" name="year" id="year" />
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs0">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs1">1B</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs0">
       <select multiple id="C" name="playArray[]" class="tabStyle" size="10">

          </select> 
        </div>
    <div id="tabs1">
      <select multiple id="FB" name="playArray[]" class="tabStyle" size="10">

          </select> 
        </div>
</div>
    <div id="bottomWrap">
        <div id="instructions"><b>Players:</b> Select up to four players.</div>
        <div id="added_players" align="center" class="added_players"></div>
        <div id="error" class="err"></div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id='start'></div>
</form>
<div id="ajaxDiv"></div>

</div>
</div>

<div id="leftcolumn">
<div class="innertube">
<div id="accordionLeft">

</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="rightcolumn">
<div class="innertube">
<div id="accordionRight">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the associated and relevant HTML code?  How can anyone reproduce your issue?  http://sscce.org/

Comment: Please also provide the php script 'newmlbcompare2.php', so that we can see what HTML you are trying to insert into your #ajaxDiv.

Comment: @Stefan. I'm trying to insert tabular data

Comment: And this tabular data is not shown in IE, right?  There must be a reason, so maybe the HTML code is invalid, or the CSS you use for that data does something to the data display in IE.  If we could see the code, we could rule out these possibilities.

Comment: I think your form tag seems to be in the wrong position. You will notice that you close the tabs with a div as well as the 'compareWrapper div before you end the form - however the first form tag is AFTER the compareWrapper div.  Should be just before it, possibly.

Comment: @Stefan...correct, the tabular data is not show in IE. Here is a sample of the table that is returned: http://pastebin.com/GVkKPjQG

Comment: It works fine for me, in IE 8.0 (and also FF 11.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @GeoffWarren, there was an error in my table structure that was being returned. Once I fixed that it worked in IE.

Thanks to all who took the time to look.

Kyle

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `$('#ajaxDiv').html(result);` to `$('#ajaxDiv').append(result);`.

Apparently IE can have some problems with .html() [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: That does not explain his problem, _"It does show results in the alert, but the page is just blank in IE."_

Comment: @Sparky672: ? Yes, the alert works (all browsers).  But calling .html() on #ajaxDiv does not work in IE.  But as Geoff says, maybe .append() will work.

Comment: Does the html being returned by your ajax call validate? An example of the result would make it easier to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @GeoffWarren Here is an example of the html that is being returned http://pastebin.com/GVkKPjQG

Comment: @relyt, I checked out the example you added to Stefan's answer and it seems to be working for me in IE9. Do you have any addons or settings which might be blocking the result?

Answer (score 0):

Possibility...? Change this:

```
 <div id="compareWrapper">

 <form name="compareit" id="compareit" action="">
```

to this:

```
 <form name="compareit" id="compareit" action="">

 <div id="compareWrapper">
```

Comment: @relyt: It seems to work for me in both Firefox and IE 8, except that in IE I see warnings like these: Warning: Division by zero in /home/fantasyp/public_html/autographaddict.com/huhTest/includes/compare_funcs.php on line 160
Warning: Division by zero in /home/fantasyp/public_html/autographaddict.com/huhTest/includes/compare_funcs.php on line 182

Comment: Yes. I fixed it. I found an error in my table structure. I turned on php errors for debugging purposes. Thanks for taking the time to look! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:'newmlbcompare2.php', 
    cache: false,
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "html", //try adding this
    success:function(result){
        $('#ajaxDiv').html(result);
        // This alerts the HTML block that is being returned (in all browsers)
        //alert(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I tried specifying dataType, but still can't get it to work.

Comment: can you do me a favor? Please paste the result of the alert. Also please to a typeof for the result variable. Also also, can you check to debug console in ie9 and paste the result. This is a weird one and I am really curious.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. It ended up that my table was malformed (missing a closing </td>). Once that was fixed, everything worked as expected.